# Why doesn't this dashboard route follow my middleware logic?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **Laravel 8** app that uses **Microsoft Azure** for user management (login included).

I began by following **[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=1)** on their website.

I have these routes "under" the **dashboard** route, that I want to protect with a piece of custom middleware:

```
// Dashboard routes
Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardContoller::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard' , 'middleware' => ['checkSignedIn']], function() {
    Route::get('/users', [UsersContoller::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/create-user', [UsersContoller::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/delete-user/{id}', [UsersContoller::class, 'delete']);
});
```

The conditions for a user to be allowed to the application's dashboard are:

1. They sign in with a valid Microsoft account
2. Their  email is inside an aray of alowed emails:

   ```
   private $allowedEmails = [
       'user.one@domain.com',
       'user.two@domain.com',
       'user.three@domain.com',
   ];
   ```

For this purpose, I have done the flollowing:

Created a `CheckSignedIn` middleware, with `php artisan make:middleware CheckSignedIn`.

Registered the above middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // More middleware
    'checkSignedIn' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSignedIn::class,
];
```

In `app\Http\Middleware\CheckSignedIn.php` I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckSignedIn {
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */

private $allowedEmails = [
    'user.one@domain.com',
    'user.two@domain.com',
    'user.three@domain.com',
];


public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
  $isSignedIn = null !== session('userName') && in_array(session('userEmail'), $this->allowedEmails);
  
      if (!$isSignedIn) {
          return redirect('/');
      }
      
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### The problem

Evan if I am **not** logged in I can still see the dashboard (the `/dashboard` route).

Shouldn't this line deal with the `/dashboard` route too?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard' , 'middleware' => ['checkSignedIn']], function() {
```

##### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your routes like this:

```php
// Dashboard routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => ['checkSignedIn']], function() {
    Route::get('/', [DashboardContoller::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/users', [UsersContoller::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/create-user', [UsersContoller::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/delete-user/{id}', [UsersContoller::class, 'delete']);
});
```

Comment: not working with my code?

Comment: No, but it was very helpful.

Comment: I see , misunderstood

Comment: The middleware should guard the `/dashboard` route too.